# Blackberry Application signing problems

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

I got the .csi files from RIM before 4 years for an blackberry application.
Can we use those .csi files again for signining other blackberry applications also ?
When i tried to run those files it shows the alert messages like "The private key could not be found,and The private key is contained in the sigtool.csk which was not found.

> Expected location:c:/blackberry/jde4.2/bin/sigtool.csk.

when i press Yes. It doesnt shows anything. what i will do ?

How is this file generated and what should I to build my application on device ?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to sign your app you should do one of:

- generate sigtool files by installing the signature keys sent to you by RIM
- copy your old sigtool files (sigtool.set, sigtool.db, sigtool.csk, SignatureTool.jar) to you new environment. However if version of new BB Plugin is newer, you should go the first way

See
[A60 – How and When to Sign](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A60_How_And_When_To_Sign_V2.pdf)
[Getting code signing keys from RIM, then using them](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=522)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Officially RIM issues keys for use on only one computer.  I don't know how they check or verify this but I have experienced this limitation - I had to get a new set of keys when I switched computers.

After 4 years I doubt you are using the same computer so you will need to get new keys.

Answer (score 0):

To sign your app you must need the files **sigtool.csk, sigtool.set** and **sigtool.db**

generally you must copy the files inside Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde\vmTools

or you will import the files from Window--> Preferences --> Blackberry Java Plug-In --> Signature Tool --> Import Existing Keys...

[Backup and Restore BlackBerry Code Signing Keys](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Backup-and-Restore-BlackBerry-Code-Signing-Keys/ta-p/837925)

[Getting code signing keys from RIM](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=522)